# Magento2 :owl carousel and other custom extension js not working on first time page load

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, requirejs, banner-slider

I am using **owl carousel** on my **magento 2** website. I have created a custom module for that.

While I am loading my website first time owl carousel slider is not appearing,.

When I move to other page and **comeback to home page** slider is appearing.

Can anyone help on this.

**requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        "*": {
            bannerowlcarousel: "Vendor_Banner/js/owl.carousel.min"
        }
    }
};
```

**banner.phtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'jquery',
        'bannerowlcarousel'
    ], function ($) {
        $("#banner-slider-demo-1").owlCarousel({
            items: 1,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplayTimeout: 5000,
            autoplayHoverPause: true,
            dots: true,
            nav: true,
            navRewind: true,
            animateIn: 'fadeIn',
            animateOut: 'fadeOut',
            loop: true,
            navText: ["<em class='icon-left'></em>","<em class='icon-right'></em>"]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: share your code here

Comment: please check the updated question.

Comment: please let me know if you have issue.

Comment: have you done static content deploy .

Comment: yes i did that.

Comment: @rajatkara  Have you changes in config.js file?

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: @rajatkara Hi I have same problem,it takes time to load owlcarousel js.Did you find solution ?

Answer (score 1):

`requirejs-config.js` :

```
var config = {
"map": {
    "*": {
        "OwlCarousel": "<vodeorname>_<modulename>/js/owl-carousel"
    }
}
```

};

`phtml` Template :

```
<?php $items = $this->getItemCollection()->getData(); ?>

<div id="owl-demo" data-mage-init='{
"OwlCarousel":{
    "autoPlay": 3000,
    "items" : 2,
    "itemsDesktop" : [1199,3],
    "itemsDesktopSmall" : [979,3]
   }
 }'>
   <?php foreach ($items as $item) { ?>
    <div class="item"><img src="<?php echo $this->imageurl . $item['item_image']; ?>" alt="Owl Image"></div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Let me know if you have an issue.

Answer (score 1):

The probable issue is that when you load your page first time your owlcarousel is not initialized and later on when you refresh your page once it does. You can try initializing without configuration first i.e as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'jquery',
        'bannerowlcarousel'
    ], function ($) {
        $("#banner-slider-demo-1").owlCarousel();
        $("#banner-slider-demo-1").owlCarousel({
            items: 1,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplayTimeout: 5000,
            autoplayHoverPause: true,
            dots: true,
            nav: true,
            navRewind: true,
            animateIn: 'fadeIn',
            animateOut: 'fadeOut',
            loop: true,
            navText: ["<em class='icon-left'></em>","<em class='icon-right'></em>"]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your requirejs-config.js file code,

```
 var config = {
        paths: {            
                'bannerowlcarousel': "Vendor_Banner/js/owl.carousel.min"
            },   
        shim: {
            'bannerowlcarousel': {
                deps: ['jquery']
            }
        }
    };
```

Remove var and clear cache.

Comment: Have you checked using above method?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `domReady!` as a require JS dependency, this will ensure the carousel is not initialised until the page has loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'jquery',
        'bannerowlcarousel',
        'domReady!'
    ], function ($) {
        // Your code
    });
```

I also recommend adding your script in a JS file rather than a template.